# Using coverFlow in the music application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have create the music application, but now I want to implement the coverflow in my application .And get code for coverFlow but I have problem with that .I want When ever  I click on cover flow image it must flip and the particular song(uiclass ) must start or come on the  screen.

It like the When tapped, albums flip over just like the original cover flow on iPod touches and iPhones.

Here is the link of the cover flow code:
http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-

Comment: Please post some code and some more references to the libraries you are using if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find the cover flow in the link. The cookbook has too many items.

Editted:

The flip animation effect needs to rotate the center image along with y-coordinate. But the original -(void)draw and -(void)drawTile:atOffset: methods are designed to scroll images, hence it is necessary to implement another methods to rotate center card only.

The following methods calculate the offset about scrolling image and redraw each scene by timer:

- -(void)startAnimation;
- -(void)drivenAnimation;
- -(void)endAnimation;

So, we can implement another method to calculate the rotate angle for flip animation and redraw as the same way.

Comment: here is another link for you check it out give me solution 
http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m